# How can I make a horizontal navigation bar that always stays at the top and is the entire width of the browser?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, nav

How can I make a horizontal navigation bar that always stays at the top and is the entire width of the browser? A good example of what I would like is something like the nav bar on http://www.agarp.co

Note that I would prefer that the nav bar is written using the Bootstrap framework.

Comment: do you mean this http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

Comment: Google 'sticky footer' and apply those concepts to a header.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use:

position: fixed;
top: 0;

on your nav bar.